# Find the fuction $g$.

Tags: functions, relations

If $f:x \mapsto x^2 + 3$, find function $g$ such that $gf:x \mapsto 2x^2 + 3$.

I don't know how to do it, there is no such example in my book.

Help?

Comment: Well in this question it doesn't make clear that $gf$ what actually means. It can be either $g∘f$ or the product $g.f$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^2+3,\quad g(f(x))=2x^2+3\\
\implies g(x^2+3)=2x^2+3=2(x^2+3)-3\\
\implies g(x)\text{ could be }g(x):=2x-3$$
If $gf=g(x)\times f(x)$, then
$$g(x)\times f(x)=2x^2+3\\
\implies g(x)=\dfrac{2x^2+3}{x^2+3}=1+\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+3}$$

Comment: nice explanation.

Comment: @Shobhit Thanks.

Comment: Since when does $gf$ denote $g\circ f$?

Comment: @GitGud I will edit my answer to if $gf=g(x)\times f(x)$.

Comment: @GitGud See my edit.

Comment: I did not understand! How did this come? $\implies g(x^2+3)=2x^2+3=2(x^2+3)-3\\$

Comment: @GitGud Since always?

Comment: @Kiara $$2(x^2+3)-3=2x^2+6-3=2x^2+3=g(x^2+3)$$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Lol? Everywhere $gf$ denotes the product.

Comment: @GitGud Any mildly lazy mathematician denotes $g\circ f$ by $gf$, and $g\cdot f$ for the product.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'm not going to discuss this. In my experience $gf$ is the product (which might coincide with composition), this is so in 95% of the literature I've set my eyes on. If the estimate doesn't generalize for all literature, then good for you. Your comment is there to alert to that possibility.

Comment: I have seen both used, and it's usually clear from context which is meant. Ergo, one should always be explicit unless it's very clear...